# What is the wildcard equivalent for boto3 dynamodb ProjectionExpression

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a function that calls boto3's query operation. My data object for each record is rather large so I have created an optional parameter that can be passed to reduce the fields that are returned. Here is the function:

```
def get_leads(type,leadTable,**kwargs):
    attributes = kwargs.get('attributes', None)
    client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = client.Table(leadTable)
    try:
        if attributes != None:
            response = table.query(ProjectionExpression=attributes,KeyConditionExpression=Key('lead_type').eq(type))
        else:
            response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('lead_type').eq(type))
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return 0
```

This way, i can optionally pass attributes as a parameter
e.g.,

`get_leads("user","table1",attributes="first_name,last_name,title,image_link")`

returns only `first_name,last_name,title,image_link` fields

OR

`get_leads("user","table1")`

returns all fields

Ideally, I would like to simplify this function and set attributes to a wildcard ProjectionExpression value when it is not defined.
e.g.,

```
def get_leads(type,leadTable,**kwargs):
    attributes = kwargs.get('attributes', "*")
    client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = client.Table(leadTable)
    try:
        return table.query(ProjectionExpression=attributes,KeyConditionExpression=Key('lead_type').eq(type))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return 0
```

Sadly, I can't seem to find documentation anywhere stating what this wildcard value is or if it even exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no wild card, the absence of a ProjectipnExpression signifies DynamoDB to return all attributes.

Another tip is not to create a client in your function, create it globally and share its state across invocations, you'll get better latency and reduced costs if you use KMS at scale.

Comment: Its executing a single time within a lambda function so ultimately I believe it would need to be initialized regardless. If you've got other ideas on that front im definitely all ears though!

Comment: If it's a Lambda get in the habit of creating your clients and other reusable resources outside of the request handler. This means they can be shared across multiple invocations and reduce startup time and latency.